# append ". " after selected item values of checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a check box list item with List items in it. When i save the form selected values should be save to database .
See my logic.

```
    string Type = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < chbCourse.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        if (chbCourse.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            Type += chbCourse.Items[i].ToString() + ",";

        }

    }
```

It is working great but because of the "," which is  i am putting between two values they are separated with each other, but at last item also it will append the "," . Is there any way to remove last "," or insert "." at last ","

Is there any logic for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join all selected items, using `string.Join` and `LINQ`:

```
Type = string.Join(",",
    chbCourse.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Text));
```

Since `string.Join` only adds the separator *between* items, it won't add an extra comma to the end.

*(Also, calling* ToString() *on a* `ListItem` *displays the class type; you have to use the* `Text` *property.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    var a="1,2,3,";
    a=a.TrimEnd(new [] {','});
    Console.WriteLine (a); //1,2,3

}
```

Comment: I can do like this also     Type.Remove(Type.Length - 1);

Comment: @Aj_sari No. this will remove also if you dont have `,` at the end

Comment: Ya but in my scenario i wont get any other character at the end!!

Comment: @Aj_sari Try not writing a case specific code when you can make it general , you never know what happens specially if you're retrieving data from a Database.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
string Type = String.Join(",", chbCourse.Items);
```

If "." is also required

```
string Type = String.Concat(String.Join(",", chbCourse.Items),".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this for selected items:

```
string Type = string.Join(",", CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(a=>a.Selected).Select(a => a.Text));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Type)) // To add '.' at end
    Type = Type + ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'd wanted to put dot (".") on the last character, then I would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chbCourse.Items.Count; i++)
{

    if (chbCourse.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        if (i == chbCourse.Items.Count - 1) Type += chbCourse.Items[i].ToString() + ".";
        else 
           Type += chbCourse.Items[i].ToString() + ",";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string Type = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < chbCourse.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        if (chbCourse.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            Type += chbCourse.Items[i].ToString() + ",";

        }
    }

    if(Type != null)
        Type = Type.TrimEnd(',');
```

Try not to use Class Names as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string Type = null;

type = String.Join(",", 
                   chbCourse.Items.Where(Function(x) x => x.Selected)
                                  .Select(Function(y) y => y.ToString()).ToArray);
```